# Trying to create Oracle Graph Instance on Cloud (DBCS)

Tags: oracle-graph

I am trying unsuccessfully to create the Oracle Graph instance on my Cloud Oracle ADB! I use the instructions from Ryota Yamanaka ['Setup Oracle Graph on Cloud (DBCS)'](https://medium.com/oracledevs/setup-oracle-graph-on-cloud-dbcs-84bc198d54a0) and it fails on `SSH Public Key:

***This variable is required.***
[image: Create Oracle Graph Instance Step 2]

Where should I get this SSH key or how should I create it?
It would be nice to clarify this as it seems to me that this is my only chance to get technically involved with Oracle Graph.

Thanks, Fried

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate an SSH key pair (= private key and public key) on your client first.

- [This](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/cloud/compute-iaas/generating_ssh_key/generate_ssh_key.html) is the instruction how to create an SSH key pair

Then, you can open the public key and copy the content.